# Flutter image comparison

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, clip-path

we are making an image display application and we need such an area. The 2 images should look like the one I posted. We tried to do it with Clippath but we couldn't get the image we wanted.

The image we want:

[image]

The image we got:

[image]

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Custom extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    print(size.width);
    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;
    print(h.toString() + " - " + w.toString());
    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.9000000, size.height * 0.9980000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9620000, size.height * 0.9600000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9940000, size.height * 0.9040000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9960000, size.height * 0.0900000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.9990000, size.height * 0.0405000,
        size.width * 0.9780000, size.height * 0.0300000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.9680000, size.height * 0.0107600,
        size.width * 0.9020000, size.height * 0.0110000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.8542600, size.height * 0.0397600);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.8100000, size.height * 0.0900000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0520000, size.height * 0.9060000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.0400000, size.height * 0.9273750,
        size.width * 0.0360000, size.height * 0.9345000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.0260200, size.height * 0.9606200,
        size.width * 0.0560000, size.height * 0.9740000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.0865200, size.height * 0.9875000,
        size.width * 0.1000000, size.height * 0.9920000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.2950000, size.height * 0.9847600,
        size.width * 0.9000000, size.height * 0.9980000);
    path0.close();

    /* Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(0, 0);

    path0.lineTo(0, h);
    path0.lineTo(w, h);
    path0.close();*/
    //path0.lineTo(0,size.height);
    // path0.lineTo(x, y);
    /*  path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.9000000, size.height * 0.9980000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9620000, size.height * 0.9600000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9940000, size.height * 0.9040000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9960000, size.height * 0.0900000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.9990000, size.height * 0.0405000, size.width * 0.9780000, size.height * 0.0300000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.9680000, size.height * 0.0107600, size.width * 0.9020000, size.height * 0.0110000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.8542600, size.height * 0.0397600);*/
    path0.close();

    return path0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

class Custom2 extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    print(size.width);
    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.0080000, size.height * 0.9460000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0240000, size.height * 0.9700000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0520000, size.height * 0.9720000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7570000, size.height * 0.2775000,
        size.width * 0.9920000, size.height * 0.0460000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 1.0022000, size.height * 0.0253000,
        size.width * 0.9760000, size.height * 0.0200000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.9440000, size.height * 0.0100000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0680000, size.height * 0.0140000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0340000, size.height * 0.0260000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0120000, size.height * 0.0540000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0080000, size.height * 0.9460000);
    path0.close();
    return path0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String oncesi = "https://i.imgur.com/TRnYyEV.png";
  String sonrasi = "https://i.imgur.com/1Zgp9iA.png";

  late double genislik;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    genislik = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                    //padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: ClipPath(
                      clipper: Custom2(),
                      child: Image.network(
                        oncesi,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                    child: ClipPath(
                      clipper: Custom(),
                      child: Image.network(
                        sonrasi,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need any `quadraticBezierTo` - all your curves are arcs, so use `arcTo` methods (but yes, it requires a little bit of math skills in order to find the rect and angles)